# How to Bundle Old Plugins into the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, warnings, bundler, deprecated

I have a rails app and get this warning whenever I start the server or rake.

`DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Matt/Orchive/Orchive/config/environment.rb:5)`

I understand that I need to move out a plugin, but I don't know how to do this. I have been to the link, but it does not give instructions.

Anyone have this problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using heroku? Heroku adds some plugins which are rails 2.3 style hence you get this warning. They say that these plugins will be working when rails 4.0 is released. Also you can shut down this warning by adding this to your development.rb or production.rb file:

```
::ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true
```

Comment: Well the plugin is "acts-as-commentable-with-threading" or something.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I have found is documented [here](http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/converting-a-more-complex-rails-2-3-style-plugin-to-non-deprecated-under-rails-3-2/).

I went with the **Make it not a gem at all** part, because I needed to be able to turn plugins on/off during my capistrano deployment, based on what flavor of the app I was deploying. Before I used config.plugins to specify what plugin to use. With this approach I'm using a "require" on config.before_configuration instead.